# choosing right project template

Tags: templates, iphone-sdk-3.0

i've a proect opening with user authentication page (asking username and password). There are some extra buttons here which the app navigate to a single page when the user clicks (up to that point there is no need for table view but from those sub screens app can navigte back to that main page). In addition, if user is authenticated then the app will navigate to a page which lists some items on it (table view) and then navigate to some detail views back and forward. And i also want my app to have core data support.
Navigation based or window-based are two major possibilities, aren't they?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are building a navigation based app.  If you look at your app without the login page, it sounds like a textbook navigation based app.  Generally a login page will be handled by just using `presentModalViewController` on top of your existing navigation controller.

Comment: thanks for your advise, but i don't know usage of presentmodaldailog. now i'm discovering...

Comment: can you please send me a link expresses presentModalDialog usage?

Comment: Basically at some point you'll need to show the login page, so you can just create a new instance of your login page view controller and then call [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:xxx]; to show it.